# preg_match start, end by word or word between space

Tags: php, preg-match

I tried to build a regex for php preg_match function, but I'm really bad with this kind of logic.

I have a list of words, ie :

"this is my-test yeah"
"test is a good thing"
"this is a good book"

The goal is to know if specific words exists in the list. example, I want to retrieve the words "yeah", "test" or "book", but only if they are full word, not a composed word like "my-test" to find test...

The regex must test if the searched word is between spaces, at start or at end of string. But I don't find the correct way.

I started with this :

```
"/^.+ (yeah|test|book|) .+/"
```

But I don't know how to made tests like : if the word is at first or end place, or if the word is between spaces... I think about something like this :

```
"/(^.+ |^)(yeah|test|book)( .+|)"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern you can use:

```
$pattern = "/\b(yeah|test|book)/";
```

The `\b` is for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Example:

```
$a = "this is my-test yeah";
$b = "test is a good thing";
$c = "this is a good book";

preg_match($mine,$a,$m1);
preg_match($mine,$b,$m2);
preg_match($mine,$c,$m3);

var_dump($m1,$m2,$m3);
```

This will print:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "book"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "book"
}
```

## Update

Since the word boundary is considering `my-test` to be 2 word here is what i suggest:

1. First do a string replace to remove the dashes
2. Run the regex pattern.

   $a = str_replace("-","",$a);
   preg_match($mine,$a,$m1);

Now this is the output you get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "yeah"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "yeah"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ibu for your answer, but it doesn't match exactly what I want... Unfortunately, the first array must return "yeah", not "test" because in the string, test is not a single word (my-test). I don't know why the "word boundary" extract "test" in the first string but it's not the behaviour I want. My final goal is to extract some classes in class attributes of a tag, and if I search "col1", I don't want to retrieve TRUE if there is a class called "single-item-col1". TRUE will be returned only if the word is at first : "col1 ...", between : "... col1 ..." or at end : "... col1"